# One lan on two ADSL modems connected to the same ISP

Tags: networking, lan, isp, adsl-router

We have two routers connected to the same ISP, both are connected to the ISP through ADSL.
Computer a is connected to router A, and b is connected to router B.

tracert from a to B is 3 hops:

1. a to A
2. A to ISP's default gateway
3. ISP's default gateway to B

This is how the network looks like:

```
                                  ---Internet---
            _______________        ______|_______        _______________  
           |               |      |              |      |               |
a-Ethernet-| ADSL Router A |-ADSL-|     ISP      |-ADSL-| ADSL Router B |-Ethernet-b
           |_______________|      |______________|      |_______________|
```

- A's internal netowrk uses 192.168.168.x (subnet mask 255.255.255.0)
- B's internal network uses 192.168.1.x (subnet mask 255.255.255.0)
- ISP's internal network uses 55.65.x.x (subnet mask is 255.255.0.0)
- ISP's Default Gateway IP address is: 98.170.201.1
- ISP doesn't isolate the clients (A and B can 'send/receive' data 'to/from' each other)
- Both a and b are windows machines
- A and B are in different locations

I hope this is informative enough, tell me if it lacks any information.

I want to put a and b into the same LAN (virtually - as if they were in a real LAN.
I don't have access to ISP's configuration as I am a client.
It's for Gaming and file transfer purposes, and it should not involve the internet as using ISP's internal network is cheaper, faster and more reliable than using the internet. That's the whole idea behind it.

Comment: Either connect them both to the same router, or connect the two routers.

Comment: @Scott added some more info about the topic, also connecting both to the same router is not possible, as both a and b are in different locations (long distance)

Comment: The fact that a and b are in different locations (long distance) is an important part of the question and should be stated *in the question*.   (The network drawing is misleading.)

Comment: @Scott which part of the drawing is misleading? how can I improve the drawing? also added the info. sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The part where the two routers look like they are right next to each other.  You could put the A subnet on the left side of the ISP, to indicate physical separation.

Comment: One solution to my problem is using a vpn service, more specifically site-to-site IPSec vpn, although I'm not sure whether it's the best solution or there are better ones.

Comment: You need to setup a VPN between the two routers. If the routers aren't able to do it, you'll need to use a separate device on each end to be the VPN endpoint. Look into tinc or openvpn.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz my own router supports that, but my friend's router doesn't.

Comment: @Volcanic96 Then you can use your router as one endpoint of the VPN, but your friend will have to use something else. If you have another router that can run Tomato or OpenWRT, you can use that just as a VPN endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put A and B into the same LAN, because you'd need to manipulate what happens on the ISP's routers do that, and even if you were asking your ISP nicely, they won't do that.

However, you can connect A's LAN with B's LAN via a [tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol), so you can *make it look* like they are in the same LAN (when in fact they aren't).

There are various ways to set that up (on A and B, on the routers if you have access, on a third machine in the local LAN; not using encryption or using encryption), so the best way to do that depends on your circumstances, the OS's you are using, and your other requirements.

One way to do it is to install an OpenVPN client on both A and B.

Comment: I know that, and that's what I'm asking for actually, putting a and b into the same LAN (virtually) as if they were in the same LAN, but I want to tunnel it through ISP's network, not the internet.

Comment: Everything, e.g. OpenVPN, that can tunnel "through the internet" also can tunnel through your ISPs network. The difference is that you have to set it up on *both* ends.